# IE8 issues - custom styled dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following custom styled drop downs controlled with jquery.  For some reason the drop down always defaults to open and doesn't close whenever an item is selected, in IE8 only.

*removed URL*

```
<section class="main">
            <div class="wrapper-demo">
                <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
                    <span>Gender</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
                        <li><a href="#">Male</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Female</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: This may not fix it but IE in particular isn't happy with broken HTML: remove the stray `</header>` end tag on line 18.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a problem maybe you not set opacity .wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown for ie. Please try code below myabe help hide dropdown menu on ie

```
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    /* Styles */
    background: #d3d3d3;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: normal; /* Cancels previous font-weight: bold; */

    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
     /* IE 8 */
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

      /* IE 5-7 */
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    pointer-events: none;

}

.wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;

     /* IE 8 */
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";

      /* IE 5-7 */
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: I added that to the .wrapper-dropdown-1 class, but it just sets the opacity of the main element.  The <li>'s are still never hidden.

Comment: please set opacity on .wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown not .wrapper-dropdown-1

Comment: I did that, but now I can't see the drop down at all.

Comment: you need set opacity 100 (.wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown) to show dropdown when active state. Please look at code above